A possible typo in Theorem $15(b)$ of B. Ja. Levin's “Distribution of Zeros of Entire Functions”?
I think there's a typo in Theorem $15(b)$ from B. Ja. Levin's book Distribution of Zeros of Entire Functions: Revised Edition. Here is a screenshot from the book:

Isn't the correct statement that "...its type is equal to the modulus of the coefficient of $z^p$..."? The type is a non-negative quantity, so $15(b)$ as written doesn't make sense for a function with a negative or complex coefficient for $z^p$, e.g. $e^{-2z^p}P(z)$ where $P(z)$ is a polynomial. Am I overlooking something?
